# How to save css property with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#coverValue").click(function(){
      var img = $("input[name='cover']:checked").val();
     $(".backgroundImage").css("background-image" , "url("+ img +")");
     $(".backgroundImage").css("background-size" , "100% 100%");
   });
});
```

So I have this code which does what it is supposed to, it applies the image to the wanted cover area. Now how do I actually save it so that the image stays on refresh?

Comment: You can use browser `localStorage` to save the CSS so that if stays after refresh.

Comment: You need to have a kind of temporary storage mech. JS has provided local storage as well as session storage

Comment: I am checking into it right now, but the problem is it is done localy right? So if another user visits the profile he will not see that image. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: If this img is profile picture then you should be storing the link in your `Database` and display the image the user visits the profile - Localstorage is not meant for storing profile picture OR picture